# sql. is there any way to write query without subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql, oracle

is there any way to write query without subquery?.

i have with:

```
with test as (
    select 1 as user_id, 'sadasdasggg1' as order_id, sysdate - 1 as order_date from dual
    union
    select 1, 'sadasdasggg2', sysdate - 2 from dual
    union
    select 1, 'sadasdasggg3', sysdate - 3 from dual
    union
    select 2, 'sadasdasggg4', sysdate - 4 from dual
)
```

i excepted to get ORDER_ID and the latest ORDER_DATE by user_id.

```
SELECT ORDER_ID, ORDER_DATE
FROM (
select s.*, row_number() over(PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY order_date desc) rn
from test s
) WHERE rn = 1
```

and it works but i want to find out how to get that result without subquery

Comment: What's wrong with the subquery? It works and it's efficient. Some DBMSs (you don't seem to be sure which you are using) allow a `QUALIFY` predicate. Or you can abuse `ORDER BY` and `WITH TIES` in SQL Server, but that's less efficient.

Comment: *"i want to find out how to get that result without subquery"* - uhh, have you compared the [query plan](https://blogs.oracle.com/optimizer/post/how-do-i-display-and-read-the-execution-plans-for-a-sql-statement)? does the one with subquery perform worse?

Comment: Yes, there are several ways. But this is the common way.

Comment: Your current approach is likely your best option on Oracle (which doesn't support `QUALIFY` AFAIK).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Oracle:

```sql
SELECT MAX(order_id) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY order_date) AS order_id,
       MAX(order_date) AS order_date
FROM   test
GROUP BY user_id
```

or, from Oracle 12:

```sql
SELECT order_id,
       order_date
FROM   test
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY order_date DESC)
FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES
```

Which, for your sample data, both output:

| ORDER_ID | ORDER_DATE |
| --- | --- |
| sadasdasggg1 | 2024-03-06 11:06:34 |
| sadasdasggg4 | 2024-03-03 11:06:34 |

[Oracle fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/jnOC4YKm)

The second option also works in PostgreSQL (from version 13) [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/XZEwqW0x)

Answer (score 3):

In PostgreSQL you can use [values](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-values.html) clause and `distinct on`.

```sql
with test(user_id, order_id, order_date) as (
 values
 (1,'sadasdasggg1',current_date-1),
 (1,'sadasdasggg2',current_date-2), 
 (1,'sadasdasggg3',current_date-3),
 (2,'sadasdasggg4',current_date-4)
)
select distinct on (user_id) order_id, order_date
from test
order by user_id, order_date desc;
```

[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3ps8mn9jS3hoRmgPdGZqbY/0)